# Modulus in Ruby always returning false

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-translation

I need to "translate" the following loop from JavaScript to Ruby:

```
for(i=0;i<=b.length-1;i++){
  if(!(i%2)){
    c+=b[i]
  }
}
```

Here is how I tried to write the same in Ruby:

```
until i == b.length-1 do
  unless i%2 == true
    c += b[i]
    i += 1
  end  
end
```

The modulus operator in Ruby, however, seems to return false all the time; which renders the whole condition meaningless.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have:

```
unless i%2 == 1
```

or, equivalently:

```
if i%2 == 0
```

The reason of unexpected behavior is that Ruby treats all values (including `0`) except `false` and `nil` as "truthy" in conditional statements.

Comment: Yes.. exactly this is the reason... +1

Answer (score 5):

Both in JavaScript and Ruby the [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) is expected to return an integer not a boolean:

```
2 % 2 
# => 0
3 % 2
# => 1
```

So, to check if `i` is even, you have to implement your condition like this:

```
unless i % 2 != 0
  # ...
```

However, for the purpose I think it's better to use one of the methods [`Integer#even?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-even-3F) and [`Integer#odd?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F):

```
if i.even?
  #...
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, `0` and `-0` are falsy values and therefore evaluate to `false` when doing comparisons. All other `Number`s evaluate to `true`.

In Ruby, there is no implicit type conversion when comparing objects, and `0` evaluates to `true`. If you want to do your comparison in Ruby, you should use

```
if i%2 == 0
```

instead of your code.